# What does a plus (+) after the file permission bits mean?

Tags: permissions, ls

I ran `ls` and found a directory that has the `+` bit set:

```
$ ls -ld /var/log/journal
drwxr-sr-x+ 3 root systemd-journal 4096 Oct  1 01:23 /var/log/journal
```

I understand `drwxr-sr-x`, but what is `+`? What is it called? What does it do?

Comment: Cross-site duplicates: https://serverfault.com/q/227852/403609, https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/26776/282701

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It means there's an ACL associated with the entry.

eg

```
$ ls -ld X
drwxr-xr-x 2 sweh sweh 4096 Feb 16 20:06 X/
$ setfacl -m u:root:rwx X
$ ls -ld X               
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 sweh sweh 4096 Feb 16 20:06 X/
$
```

You can read the ACL with the `getfacl` command:

```
$ getfacl X
# file: X
# owner: sweh
# group: sweh
user::rwx
user:root:rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::r-x
```

Comment: More precisely, according to the GNU `info coreutils ls`, the `+` indicates a file with "any other combination of alternate access methods"  other than SELinux.