# Understanding group permissions - can't cd into a folder owner by group that I am member of

Tags: permissions, group

Can someone please explain to me why I am unable to cd into the folder 2024 in this screenshot (the OS is truenas scale):

[image: console screenshot]

the folder I am in has a folder called 2024 that is owned by another user - garagePi and owned by the group media. I am a member of media and the folder has read write and execute permissions for the group (as far as I can tell, I am by no means an expert on linux).

Why can't I cd into the folder? I have tried closing and restarting my ssh session to see if it needed a new login but it made no difference.

Many thanks

Comment: There may be things other than simple file permissions involved in this case - see for example [What does a plus (+) after the file permission bits mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/501108/what-does-a-plus-after-the-file-permission-bits-mean)